# PARTITION BY expression references column sku which is neither grouped nor aggregated

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I am trying to execute this query

```
select
rank() over (partition by substr(upper(sku),1,19) order by round(avg(inpf.amount),2) desc) as ranking from erp.input_factor  inpf
```

I keep getting an error:
PARTITION BY expression references column SKU which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [5:40]

of course, I do not wish to add sku to group by which is why it is in over clause.  what looks wrong here?

actual query:

```
select sq.fab_id , sq.sku as sku
from
(
select upper(inpf.fab_id) as fab_id, substr(upper(sku),1,19) as sku ,round(avg(inpf.amount),2) as amount,
  rank() over (partition by substr(upper(sku),1,19) order by round(avg(inpf.amount),2) desc) as ranking ,
fi.main_construction as construct from erp.input_factor  inpf
left join
erp.fabric_information fi
on upper(inpf.fab_id) = upper(fi.fab_id)

where length(inpf.fab_id) > 3
group by inpf.fab_id , substr(upper(sku),1,19) , fi.main_construction
) sq
where (sq.construct = 1)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help, as well as a description of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: It would be better to provide some source table description and sample of data. I'm just guessing the problem is with ```order by round(avg(inpf.amount),2) desc```. ``Avg()`` is aggregate function and neither you have ``group by`` clause, nor ``avg()`` is the only column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is peculiarity of BigQuery.  A simple solution is a subquery:

```
select sq.fab_id , sq.sku as sku
from (select upper(inpf.fab_id) as fab_id, sku19 as sku, 
             round(avg(inpf.amount),2) as amount,
             rank() over (partition by sku19 order by inpf.amount desc) as ranking,
            fi.main_construction as construct
      from erp.input_factor inpf left join
           (select fi.*, substr(upper(sku), 1, 19) as sku19
            from erp.fabric_information fi
           ) fi
           on upper(inpf.fab_id) = upper(fi.fab_id)
      where length(inpf.fab_id) > 3
      group by inpf.fab_id, sku19 , fi.main_construction
     ) sq
where sq.construct = 1;
```

Note:  You don't note where `sku` comes from, so I just guessed.

Comment: The change because we cannot use function on partition by column?

Comment: is that the case?

Comment: @Simrankaur . . . I think it is related to the `group by` key, not specifically to the use of a function.